# How to solve "Curl ERROR: couldn't connect to host" on Linux server?

Tags: php, curl

I am posting data via CURL request to another server on port 2443, everything is working fine on local environment windows, but when i move script to live linux,  i am getting the following error:

"Curl ERROR: couldn't connect to host."

My code is:

```
    <?php
$response_curlerror = "";
$response_curl = "";
$ch = curl_init("https://demo-ipg.ctdev.comtrust.ae");
$arr_sendRequest = array();
$arr_sendRequest['Currency'] = "USD";
$arr_sendRequest['TransactionHint'] = "CPT:Y;VCC:Y;";
$arr_sendRequest['OrderID'] = "1211121";
$arr_sendRequest['OrderName'] = "Paybill";
$arr_sendRequest['Channel'] = "Web";
$arr_sendRequest['Amount'] = "100";
$arr_sendRequest['Customer'] = "Demo Merchant";
$arr_sendRequest['UserName'] = "xxxxxxxxx";
$arr_sendRequest['Password'] = "xxxxxxxxx";
$arr_sendRequest['ReturnPath'] = "https://localhost:8080//Fainalize.aspx";
$jonRequest = json_encode(array('Registration' => $arr_sendRequest), JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
print "Json-submitted" . $jonRequest;
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0); /* Set to 1 to see HTTP headers, otherwise 0 or XML reading will not work */
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type:application/json', 'Accept:text/xml-standard-api'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PORT, 2443);
// curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PORT, 80);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $jonRequest);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL, 1);

// curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, "https://demo-ipg.ctdev.comtrust.ae"); //your proxy url
// curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYPORT, "80"); // your proxy port number

$response_curl = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    $response_curlerror = curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close($ch);
?>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
    <?php
    /* Generate some output */
    /* STEP 3 */
    /* Show results of submitting request using TLS 1.2 */
    print "<br />Result of Submission:<br />";
    if (strlen($response_curlerror) > 0) {
        print "Curl ERROR: " . $response_curlerror . "<br />";
    } else {
        print "-->" . $response_curl . "<br />";
    }
    ?>
</body>

</html>
```

I am getting proper response when I run it on local system windows, not sure whats the problem on live?

Comment: _"I am getting the following error:"_ - You haven't posted an error, just your code so we have _no idea_ where to start looking.

Comment: sorry, the error is Curl ERROR: couldn't connect to host"